# cv2.imread() for uint16 tiff file not reading my data correctly

Tags: python, opencv, visualization

I have a TIFF file I'd like to read with dimensions (3,1200,1200).
I want to use opencv to read and do more things to the file, but using the function cv2.imread is giving me issues. Originally, if I use tifffile.imread, the data structure has the following dimensions:

[image]
However, if I use cv2.imread and use cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED, it gets rid of the channels, i.e., my array is now of dimensions (1220,1200) as you can see below:

[image]
This is the [link](https://buckeyemailosu-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/arteagamuniz_1_buckeyemail_osu_edu/EZDMwMjge3hJtoFdulq6V_IBB8lUoWKqkp7b7GXpfsvR7w?e=zv5IfY)  to the file in case you want to download it to troubleshoot.

My code is here:

````
import cv2 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import measure, color, io

file_path = "C:\\Users\\valit\\OneDrive - The Ohio State University\\Valeria\\20230228_cdk4\\dmso\\AVG_3.tif"

img1 = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)



plt.imshow(img1) ```
````

Comment: "My code is here" -- and you ran it and it didn't crash due to a missing import of `cv2`? Anyway, without having the TIFF in question to be able to reproduce the problem, it's hard to say...

Comment: @DanMašek thannks! I forgot to include that part of the code but of course, I have it on mine. I am attaching a link with the file. Please let me know if you have a chance to check it out.  https://buckeyemailosu-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/arteagamuniz_1_buckeyemail_osu_edu/EZDMwMjge3hJtoFdulq6V_IBB8lUoWKqkp7b7GXpfsvR7w?e=zv5IfY

Comment: That is a TIFF consisting of 3 separate pages, each of which is a 1200x1200 grayscale bitmap.  OpevCV by default only reads the first page.  You should be able to use `imreadmulti` to get all of the pages.